# react-router-dom: clicking on Link adds the route to the Url indefinately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, navbar, react-router-dom

Basically, if I click on one of the navbar links, i.e. `hotmelt`, `pressureSensitive`, `liquids`.

`http://localhost:3000/hotmelt` ,
`http://localhost:3000/pressure-sensitive` ,
`http://localhost:3000/liquid`

Then click one of the types of adhesives listed under one of those pages, ie `fg3000`

`http://localhost:3000/pressure-sensitive/fg3000`

it shows the item clicked. BUT, when I click on another navbar link,
i.e. `hotmelt`,
instead of removing the `pressure-sensitive/fg3000` and looking like this: `http://localhost:3000/hotmelt`

I get this: `http://localhost:3000/pressure-sensitive/hotmelt`

so I have one navlink path sitting in front of the other in the url, thus not showing anything on the page.

the only fix i have currently, is using the back button in the browser. and that lets the url follow the logical order.

I'm assuming I'm using a reusable component as a variable link in a way that maybe is causing the issue.

here's app.js

```
<Route exact path="/hotmelt" component={Hotmelt} />
<Route exact path="/hotmelt/:id" component={SingleAdhesive} />
<Route exact path="/liquid" component={Liquid} />
<Route exact path="/liquid/:id" component={SingleAdhesive} />
<Route exact path="/pressure-sensitive" component={PressureSensitive} />
<Route exact path="/pressure-sensitive/:id" component={SingleAdhesive} />
```

Notice how `SingleAdhesives` is used multiple times. Depending on one of three different adhesives. I have a feeling that's mixing things up? I'm just not sure how else to go about it?

[Here's my git repo for this web app](https://github.com/Sebastian-Russo/ad-spec)

Thank you for your thoughts/comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doubting in the answer so I downloaded the repo to test it. On your navbar component, your Link's components have something like this:

```
<Link to="hotmelt" className="nav-link text-white" >Hot Melt<span className="sr-only"></span></Link>
```

Just add a `/` before the hotmelt like this:

```
<Link to="/hotmelt" className="nav-link text-white" >Hot Melt<span className="sr-only"></span></Link>
```

...and it will work fine!

Comment: dude, thank you! i don't have enough points here to up vote you, (first question I've posted) but i can't thank you enough!! such a silly thing... thank you.